# memory leak in C++ function, visual studio 2012, linked list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks, linked-list

Someone please help with this memory leak problem!
In my `projectInsert()`function I created a `new` pointer and after `return`, I deleted the pointer using `delete`. But the memory leak is still there. What am I doing wrong. Please help!

```
struct HeliostatPointer { double x; double y; double z; double aa; bool Corner; double SB; double spillage; bool intersect; double lw; double lh; double xx; double yy; double distance; HeliostatPointer* next; RV SunRayVector; RV ReflectedRayVector; double incident; double COS; RV NormalVector; HeliostatPointer* next2; HeliostatPointer* next3; };

HeliostatPointer* projectInsert(double ax, double ay, double az) 
{
    HeliostatPointer *temp = new HeliostatPointer;
    temp->x = ax;
    temp->y = ay;
    temp->z = az;
    temp->intersect = false;
    temp->Corner = true;
    return temp;
    delete temp->next, temp->next2, temp->next3, temp;
}
```

Comment: have you tried putting `delete temp->next, temp->next2, temp->next3,temp;` before `return temp;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant delete after return, you must delete it before the return!

The keyword return ends the function hence the delete is never executed

Comment: Oh my god.. I feel so relieved and dum haha! Thank you sooo much!!

Comment: But if I delete before return, then I cant return..right?

Comment: You right! [See here how to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992925/c-correct-way-to-return-pointer-to-array-from-function)

Answer (score 0):

You'd batter use std::shared_ptr like this

```
#include <memory>
struct Data
{

};
std::shared_ptr<Data> Test()
{
    Data* data = new Data();
    std::shared_ptr<Data> ptr(data);
    return ptr;
}
```

ptr will be released when the call end.
and data will be released when all containers are released